# ssis package unexpected termination

Tags: ssis

I am migrating reporting guff to a new 2016 sql server.

One integration package which I have upgraded, deployed and created a job for runs and then terminates unexpectedly.  The only messages are that validation starts then it terminates.

The event viewer just shows a warning saying the job failed.

The package is run by a proxy account that also has access to a file share with excel documents on it. If I run Management studio with that account and manually execute the package I get the exact same messages.  So I don't think it has anything to do with the account or permissions etc. If I run the package in visual studio it works fine.

Any suggestions on next trouble shooting steps??  Or how I can view better logs/ error files??

Thanks in advance
Kirsty

Comment: have you tried placing the package on the file system and running it with an ssis client (i.e. dtexec.exe)?

Comment: SSIS in sql 2014 has multiple bugs. Depending on your environment it may be helpful if you check the following link. Microsoft provides cumulative service packs for multiple issues. https://www.sswug.org/alexanderchigrik/sql-server/troubleshooting-sql-server-2014-integration-services/

Comment: I have recently solved a similar issue - check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66985851/ssis-error-when-run-via-sql-job-while-connecting-to-ms-access-database-unexpect/67232944#67232944