# SSIS error when run via SQL job while connecting to ms-access database (Unexpected Termination)

Tags: ms-access, ssis

I have a OLEDB task that connects to ms-access database on local file system and dumps data into sql database.

Access db connection string is: `Data Source=\\my-share\accessdbfile.accdb;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;`

The SSIS package runs OK in visual studio. Access 2016 32-bit runtime is installed on this computer.

After deployment to SSIS catalog, right click and execute works OK. Access 2016 64-bit runtime is installed on this computer.

When this package is scheduled to run via SQL Agent job, using proxy/credential [domain user - example: domainname\user1] (having read permission on the access db file), then the job fails. The SSIS execution report shows error as: **Unexpected Termination**. There is no further information.

Suppose if I add the proxy credential (domainname\user1) to the local administrators group (in computer management) then the SQL Job runs OK. What could be the solution to this so I can give only the minimum required permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is very difficult to debug as it doesn't occur when running via visual studio. Even when deployed to the SQL server and run from the SSIS catalog, the execution works OK. The error occurs only when the package is run via SQL server agent job (via credential/proxy) - the SSIS execution report doesn't show any helpful messages; and surprisingly the error gets resolved when the credential is added as local administrator on the computer - which is a bad practice.

The **solution** is analyse what kind of ms access file you are using and appropriately use the correct access runtime version (2013 vs 2016) and the correct provider value in the connection string.

**Access runtime:**

In my case, I uninstalled Access 2016 64-bit runtime and installed Access 2013 64-bit runtime.

**Provider version:**

I changed the provider version from 16.0 to 15.0, as shown below-

Before: `Data Source=\\my-share\accessdbfile.accdb;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;`

After: `Data Source=\\my-share\accessdbfile.accdb;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;`

**Note:**

1. There is **no need to add the user to the local administrator** group.
2. There is no need to login to the computer using that account.
3. Only read permission (under windows folder security) is sufficient assuming the SSIS packge will only read the ms access database.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug this only with the information provided, but in general:

The user running the job requires at least write and delete access on the underlying folder in which the Access database resides. This is required to generate a lockfile for the database.

If this is undesirable because the job may be modified by a malicious user, I've seen deployments where a copy is made in a temporary folder with write access and a size quota, and that temporary folder is removed as soon as the job finishes, regardless of if the job succeeded.

Comment: Erik I have resolved the issue, the error is related to access runtime engine version. I will post the answer separately. By the way, are you 100% sure that write permission is required? Because it works for me with only read permission.

Comment: Hi Erik could you confirm the above please?

Answer (score 0):

I usually debug with this query (run in SSISDB). It shows the error that stopped it. If there isn't and error here then it might not be SSIS related issue. The query is:

```
SELECT  [execution_id]
      ,o.[message]
      ,[project_name]
      ,[package_name]
      ,[start_time]
      ,[end_time]

          ,case 
          when [status]=3 then 'canceled'
            when [status]=4 then 'failed'  
            when [status]=5 then 'pending' 
            when [status]=6 then 'ended unexpectedly '
            when [status]=8 then 'stopping' 
        end
           as [status]
      ,[executed_as_name]
      ,[created_time]
      ,[caller_name]
      ,[process_id]
      ,[server_name]
      ,[total_physical_memory_kb]
      ,[available_physical_memory_kb]
      ,[total_page_file_kb]
      ,[available_page_file_kb]
      ,[cpu_count]
      ,[executed_count]
  FROM [SSISDB].[catalog].[executions] e
  join [SSISDB].[catalog].[operation_messages] o on o.message_type=120 and operation_id=execution_id
  where [status] not in  ('7','9')
  order by start_time desc
```